# Add dependencies to a custom target

Tags: cmake

I need a way to add additional dependencies to a custom target. I have a macro which adds resource files to a particular project, used like this:

```
ADD_RESOURCES( ${TARGET} some/path pattern1 pattern2 )
ADD_RESOURCES( ${TARGET} another/path pattern1 )
```

I create a target called `${TARGET}_ASSETS` and would like to attach the generation of all these resources to the one target. `add_dependencies` however only accepts other targets. So if I produce a file via a `add_custom_command` I cannot use that as a dependency.

The workaround might be to just create a new custom taget for each call to `ADD_RESOURCES` and then attached that to the ASSETS target. Each target requires a unique name however, and these is no way to generate this unique name from the parameters of ADD_RESOURCES.

Comment: `So if I produce a file via a add_custom_command I cannot use that as a dependency.` No problem, just `add_custom_target()` that depend on this file.

Comment: The problem is that target needs a name, a unique name, and I call the same macro multiple times.

Comment: You can define `ADD_RESOURCES` in such way, that it will be called like this: `ADD_RESOURCES(${TARGET} "some/path pattern1 pattern2" "another/path pattern1")`. Or you can't do this for some reason?

Comment: I probably could, but then the syntax starts getting confusing, and even more prone to error.

Comment: Really? You'd prefer `add_executable(foo foo.c)`, `add_executable(foo bar.c)`, `add_executable(foo baz.c)` instead of `add_executable(foo foo.c bar.c baz.c)`? Just place each group of arguments on the new line.

Answer (score 1):

One work-around is to postpone the generation of the `${target}_ASSETS` custom targets until all dependencies have been set up with calls to `ADD_RESOURCES`.

Instead of immediately adding the dependencies to the custom target, the macro `ADD_RESOURCES` has to record the dependencies in a global variable, whose name depends on the target:

```
macro (ADD_RESOURCES _targetName)
    set (_dependencies ${ARGN})
    ...
    # record depencies in a target dependency variable
    if (DEFINED ${_targetName}_Dependencies)
        list (APPEND ${_targetName}_Dependencies ${_dependencies})
    else()
        set (${_targetName}_Dependencies ${_dependencies})
    endif()
endmacro()
```

Then add another helper macro which determines all defined target dependency variables through reflection and sets up a custom target for each target:

```
macro (SETUP_ASSETS_TARGETS)
    get_cmake_property(_vars VARIABLES)
    foreach (_var ${_vars})
        if (_var MATCHES "(.+)_Dependencies")
            set (_targetName ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
            set (_targetDependencies ${${_var}})
            message("${_targetName} depends on ${_targetDependencies}")
            add_custom_target(${_targetName}_ASSETS DEPENDS ${_targetDependencies})
        endif()
    endforeach()
endmacro()
```

In your `CMakeLists.txt` add all necessary dependencies with calls to `ADD_RESOURCES`, then call the `SETUP_ASSETS_TARGETS` macro to have all custom targets defined.

```
ADD_RESOURCES( target1 some/path pattern1 pattern2 )
ADD_RESOURCES( target1 another/path pattern1 )
ADD_RESOURCES( target2 foo/bar pattern1 )
...
...
SETUP_ASSETS_TARGETS()
```

Comment: I thought of this approach. It can work, but I was hoping I wouldn't need that last step (somebody will eventually forget it and wonder why it isn't working).  Thought in fairness I might need a final step anyway (need to a lot more than just setup these resources).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but i post my solution for everyone who searches for this problem:

```
function(target_resources THIS)

    if (NOT TARGET ${THIS}_res)
        # this is just a pseudo command which can be appended later
        add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${THIS}_dep COMMAND cd ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

        # add a dependency with a target, as a command itself can not be a dependency
        add_custom_target(${THIS}_res DEPENDS ${THIS}_dep)
        add_dependencies(${THIS} ${THIS}_res)
    endif ()

    get_target_property(RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${THIS} RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)

    foreach (RES_FILE IN LISTS ARGN)

        if (IS_ABSOLUTE ${RES_FILE})
            file(RELATIVE_PATH PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${RES_FILE})
        endif ()

        # append the resource command with our resource
        add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${THIS}_dep
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
                ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${RES_FILE}
                ${RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/${RES_FILE}
                APPEND)

    endforeach ()

endfunction()
```

The benefit of this solution is that is does not rely on global variables nor the need to invoke a setup macro.